# Assembly, multiple arguments -m32 / linux (same as stdarg in C)

Tags: c, assembly, format, arguments

To solve this, I understand C, and I'm still a beginner in Assembly so I'm kinda stuck with a little problem here.

I'm having some trouble with taking multiple arguments, maybe count them if I should do that, and use the format arguments in my assembly code.

Trying to add some bytes to a string with many arguments. I know how to put the two first arguments on the stack, but the other arguments after the first is the format (like %s, %d, %c etc) and the first argument is the one that is supposed to be the variable i want to write to.
In C, standard main has argument-counter. I might want to count the arguments here aswell!? How can I do that, if that's how It's done?

```
     .globl minisprintf

# Name:         minisprintf
# Synopsis:     A simplified sprintf
# C-signature:      int minisprintf(unsigned char *res, unsigned char *format, ...);
# Registers:        AL: for characters      
#                 %ECX: first argument, res
#                 %EDX: second argument, args
#



minisprintf:                    # minisprintf

    pushl       %ebp            # start of
    movl        %esp, %ebp      # function

    movl        8(%ebp), %ecx   # first argument
    movl        12(%ebp), %edx  # second argument
                                # other arguments
                                # checking last byte of string res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variadic functions are a C feature, so you might be best served by checking out how an open-source implementation of `va_start`, `va_arg`, and `va_end` for the architecture/ABI you're interested in.

You don't need an explicit argument count for a `printf`-like function, because that information is embedded in the format string - the number and types of the variadic arguments to expect are given by the number and details of the format specifiers.

You *will* need to understand the procedure-call aspects of your ABI is pretty serious detail to get all of this working correctly.  For example, do floating point and integer arguments go to the same stack, or are some passed in registers?  What size do you need to promote types to to make sure that your `va_arg` equivalent always gets the right thing for the right type at the right time?  And so on...

Comment: I read a little about it. Seems like I can't use registers for the arguments. Can't find out how to do it. Was hoping it wasn't too much code. If there's many arguments, I shouldn't put them in registers right?

Comment: If I know how many arguments this function was able to take, that would've been great, but now I need to make sure it takes at least two arguments up to a infinite number of arguments.

Comment: @KimJonatanWesselBjørneset, the use of registers and stack for a function call is defined by your ABI/procedure call standard.  If you're inventing your own ABI, you can do whatever you want.  Remember that you have a limited number of registers, though, so you'll probably need some way to put extras on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

The way i would do it, is as follows:

You already know the first two arguments. The next argument would be on 16(%ebp), so I would put this address into a registers and use it as the base address. Now I parse my string, because this gives me the information how many registers I need. For each argument encountered, get the value from my base address and increase it by four, as the next argument will be there.

I suppose there is no real need to have all arguments in register at the same time, because you probably will scan the formatstirng sequentially.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking that could be a good solution. Trying to increase the address by four after every argument now. Except I'm not sure how... tried addl 4(%ebp), but I get seg fault when running :(

Comment: You are increasing the memory instead of the register. You must do "add 4, %reg"

Comment: If you are unsure about adressingmodes I would write a simple C program and look at the compiler output. You can let the compiler create an asm file you can look at which is very instrcutive.

Comment: I see. Like this: movb 16(%ebp, %ebx, 4), %al # next arg