# Assembly; does anyone know how to take many arguments into a function? (linux, -m32, x86)

Tags: assembly, arguments

Making a function supposed to take multiple arguments, maybe up to ten arguments. But i get stuck when I see that my registers don't have enough space fore it. Anyone have a clue what to do?

```
                    .globl myfunction    
 myfunction:

          pushl     %ebp                    # start of
          movl      %esp, %ebp              # function

          movl      8(%ebp), %ecx           # first argument
          movl      12(%ebp), %edx          # second argument
          movl      16(%ebp), %eax          # this gonna fill all the space
```

Comment: maybe you could do it the same way compilers do?

Comment: This question looks pretty much the same as your other one: [Assembly, multiple arguments -m32 / linux (same as stdarg in C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385519/assembly-multiple-arguments-m32-linux-same-as-stdarg-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of putting all the arguments into the registers in the beginning of the function, you could instead get the argument when you first need it. I don't know what the function is supposed to do, but as an example with 4 arguments where you just want to add all of arguments together it would look like this:

```
.globl myfunction    
myfunction:
      pushl     %ebp                    # start of
      movl      %esp, %ebp              # function

      movl      8(%ebp), %eax           # first argument
      movl      12(%ebp), %edx          # second argument
      addl      (%edx), %eax            # adding second argument to first

      movl      16(%ebp), %edx          # third argument
      addl      (%edx), %eax            # adding third argument

      movl      20(%ebp), %edx          # forth argument
      addl      (%edx), %eax            # adding forth argument
      ...
```

Hope this helps.

In response to your comment, I would think you could do the following:

```
movl %ebp, %ecx
addl $8, %ecx       # ecx does now point to the first argument

movl (%ecx), %eax  # copies the first argument to eax
addl $4, %ecx       # moves to the next argument

movl (%ecx), %eax  # copies the second argument to eax
addl $4, %ecx       # moves to the next argument

movl (%ecx), %eax  # copies the third argument to eax
...
```

Comment: thanks, I'm trying to make my own version of the function in C called sprintf. It takes an infinite number of arguments, (but at least two is minimum) and adds it to the first parameter. It's kinda complicated, including stdarg.h. I'll try to add the arguments :)

Comment: do you know if I can in some way, write incl (%ebp) or something like that? To increase the address by four each time I'm getting to an arg !? That would be great.

Comment: good idea :) have to clean up a bit and I'll test a few things with that example you gave me :D

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work. Maybe there is something i do wrong? I'm trying to increse the address by 4 each time but, I get segmentation fault all the time :/

Comment: Are you changing ecx, cx, ch or cl between reading the arguments? Or maybe you are calling a function in between reading the arguments? In that case you must save the value of ecx by for example pushing it before calling the function, and popping it when returning from the function.

Comment: I just noticed that I were missing the $ sign for the numbers, so if you didn't add them yourself, you should. Don't know what it means when it is not there..

Comment: this was the code i was looking for:

movb  16(%ebp, %ebx, 4), %al # next arg